# Replacing items in a QTableWidget

Tags: qt, qt4, qt5, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

If I create a new `QTableWidgetItem` and insert/set into a cell on a `QTableWidget` that already has an existing item, is the previous itemy deleted or will there be a memory leak?  Do I need to retrieve the existing item and change its properties?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you insert a `QTableWidgetItem` into a `QTableWidget` using `QTableWidget::setItem()` the table takes ownership of the item, which means that it will manage it for you. If you call `setItem()` for a column and row that already has an item, the table will delete the old item for you. So no memory leak. You're safe!